# Background concurrent copying GC freed - app crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

i got this message after crashes app (after 3sec run on emulator):

`Background concurrent copying GC freed 48349(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 1.116ms total 108.902ms`

Memory on emulator:
RAM: 1536MB
VM heap: 228

Can it be a mistake to have a small ram memory? Or what?
In activity where app crashes, I call firebase api and after that, i call db request, but that should't be a problem :(